# A simple estimation/approximation of square root

Tags: triangles, radicals, square-numbers

Someone works in a kitchen cabinetry workshop and his calculator/phone doesn't have a square root function. He intends to use Pythagorean theorem to calculate *right triangle* sides for cabinet doors etc. like:

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

He asked me to provide him a formula consisting of `-`, `+`, `/` and `*` operations. Note that his math knowledge is *not* sophisticated, therefor his is *not* able to use iterative approaches. I researched for a rational estimation, but I couldn't find a proper one. I wonder if anybody can help.

Comment: Could he use the binomial theorem after taking out the nearest perfect square?

Comment: @SameerBaheti Based on his math knowledge, I think it is *not* that straightforward for him to find the closest perfect square!

Comment: If he needs an approximate answer, shouldn't he be able to find a perfect square so close such that (actual number - perfect square)/perfect square is much less than the perfect square?

Comment: @SameerBaheti Well, he is *not* sophisticated in math. He just needs a formula into which numbers are plugged and he gets the answer easily!

Comment: Fortunately for him/her , to approximate $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ with $a\ge b$ (WLOG) it is not necessary to find the closest perfect square. A formula for him/her can be derived with the taylor expansion. But it is not clear whether this is the only thing he needs.

Comment: @Peter Nice idea. Truncating Taylor series can give a simple enough formula =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can assume that $a$ and $b$ are measured in $m$ and barely won't exceed $10$ , the following approximation should be good enough for $a\ge b$ :

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\approx \frac{a(5b^4+20a^2b^2+16a^4)}{b^4+12a^2b^2+16a^4}$$

Comment: This is a higher-degree pade-approximation

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Peter comment and this [Taylor expansion post](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Supplemental_Modules_(Analysis)/Series_and_Expansions/Taylor_Expansion_II), the square root of a number `x` can be approximated by such a formula:

$\sqrt{x}\approx 1+\dfrac{(x-1)}{2}-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{8}+\dfrac{(x-1)^3}{16}-\dfrac{5(x-1)^4}{128}+\dfrac{7(x-1)^5}{256}-\dfrac{21(x-1)^6}{1024}+\dfrac{231(x-1)^7}{14336}$

I'm going to introduce this equation to the wood-working guy. Hopefully it is simple enough.

Comment: I rather wanted to expand $\sqrt{1+x^2}$  at $x=0$ , one issue is : the larger $a$ is, the more terms do we need to get a reasonable approximation , in particular if $a\approx b$

Comment: @Peter Right. Considering the range of values in a wood-working workshop: from a few centimeters to hundreds of centimeters, is my formula valid? Just wondering! :)

Comment: Using the pade-approximation, we get $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\approx \frac{a(3b^2+4a^2)}{b^2+4a^2}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110131/discussion-between-peter-and-user3853917).